# Tool to keep track of our maintainance modifications to many similar websites

Tags: software-development, web-development, issue-tracker

We are maintaining a lot of similar websites.

We are looking for a tool which simplify our work:

- Declare a task, that changes code.
  [e.g  mark active menu bar]
- Declare the pages that need to be changed.
  [e.g. 
  style.css - add rule, 
  menu.php - add class to the active menu-bar]
- Mark which code changes were done
- Duplicate all to some projects that are updated in parallel, each has specific code
  [e.g. 
  menu-color-1 for site1, 
  menu-color-2 for site2]
- Mark which tasks were done.
- Query which sites were not updated yet.
  [e.g. site2, task7 was done]
- Query which code changes were done on specific page
  [e.g. on style.css]
- It would be nice if we could look on all tasks, and expand specific task to see the related pages.

Can you recommend a tool for this?

[meanwhile we are using google-spreadsheet-doc - but it becomes very large . .  .]

Comment: Do you use git?